# Looking for two 5x5 matrices that have the same characteristic and minimal polynomials but they are not similar

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

> Give an example of two 5x5 matrices that have the same characteristic and minimal polynomials but they are not similar.

I've been thinking about this for a while but I can't find any example that satisfies the request. I would be grateful if someone could give me an example.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work over $\mathbb{C}$. Consider the Jordan canonical form

**Hint:** What does it mean that the minimal polynomials are the same?

> For each eigenvalue $\lambda$, the maximal block has the same size.

**Hint:** What does it mean that the characteristic polynomials are the same?

> For each eigenvalue $\lambda$, the dimensions of the generalized eigenspace are the same.

So, how do we find such an example?

**Hint:** $1+1+1+2 = 1 + 2 + 2$.

> Consider Jordan blocks corresponding to $x \times x \times x \times x^2$ and $ x \times x^2 \times x^2$

---

**Followup:** Is 5 the smallest dimension for such an example?
Can you find an example in dimension 4?
Can you find an example in dimension 3?

Comment: Your second hint is not correct as it is. We need the *generalized* eigenspaces to have equal dimensions.

Comment: Yes indeed. I've added that in. I thought that was obvious by talking about Jordan form.